# How to write F# Type Provider to generate P/Invoke code?

Tags: f#, pinvoke, type-providers

I was trying to develop a native C interop library in F#.

I wonder if there is a way to leverage F# type provider to read that C library header file, parse it and use the AST to generate the boilerplate P/Invoke binding code.

I read several type provider projects code, but there still things unclear to me, specifically the following:

1. How to mark a `ProvidedMethod` as `extern`?
2. How to generate a plain struct (value type) with `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)` attributes?

Please give any suggestion to me, thanks!